# AE composition with MOV footage not rendering in Media Encoder

Tags: after-effects, adobe-media-encoder

I am relatively new to After Effects and Media Encoder.

I have an application that is monitoring a folder for media delivered by a 3rd party. When that media arrives, I move the media to a watch folder setup in Media Encoder together with an AE project file - the intention being that Media Encoder will render out an MP4 file that I can then use elsewhere.

The AE project file contains a composition that renders (among other things) some MOV footage. The application, AE and Media Encoder are all installed on a Windows 10 virtual machine. AE is configured as a render-only node. I also have the HEVC and HEIF extensions installed.

This is largely working as expected - except the MOV footage is rendered as a test pattern. All other parts of the composition are rendered correctly.

If I drop the MOV footage directly into Media Encoder, the footage is rendered correctly.

If I configure AE so that it is not a render-only node, the MOV footage is rendered correctly.

If I try the same setup, but with aerender.exe, the same thing happens - where the MOV footage is expected, there is just a black screen.

The same happens even if I drop the files into the watch folder manually. I've even tried collecting the files to the same location - still no joy.

Has anyone experienced anything like this and able to offer some advice please? Or perhaps how best to include MOV footage in a composition? If necessary I could pre-convert the MOV footage to MP4 (or other format) to be used in the composition instead. I have spoken to Adobe about this, but unfortunately they were unable to help as this is the first time they've seen this issue...